# AWS DynamoDB parsing returned data

Tags: javascript, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to use JS to query DynamoDB and parse the returned data. I must admit that I am new to JavaScript but I am having some weird behaviours.

In the following function I am passing an array of dates and I am retrieving objects from my table

```
var queryDynamo = function(dateArray){
  console.log(dateArray)
  for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
    var params = {
        TableName : "myTable",
        KeyConditionExpression: "#day = :st ",
        ExpressionAttributeNames:{
            "#day": "day"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':st': dateArray[i]
        }
    };
    var resp = docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
                console.log("ERR:"+JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2))
            } else {
                data.Items.forEach(function(element) {
                    console.log(element)
                });        
            }
        });
      }
      console.log(resp.response)
      return;
    }
```

--> The following is the output

```
constructor {request: constructor, data: null, error: null, retryCount: 0, redirectCount: 0, …}
        data:
          Count: 4
          Items: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
          ScannedCount: 4
          __proto__: Object
          error: null
        httpResponse: constructor {statusCode: 200, headers: {…}, body: Uint8Array(1134), streaming: false, stream: i, …}
        maxRedirects: 10
        maxRetries: 10
        nextPage: ƒ (e)
        redirectCount: 0
        request: constructor {domain: undefined, service: t.c…r.t.constructor, operation: "query", params: {…}, httpRequest: constructor, …}
        retryCount: 0
        __proto__: Object
```

The query succeeds but the result is kind of weird.

- resp.response correctly contains the `data` object but I cannot access it. It says that it's `null` while it clearly is not since it has 4 Items.

  Any thoughts?

Comment: The DocumentClient methods return an AWS.Request object. The response data will be contained in an AWS.Response object (which is the context of the callback function) and also in the data parameter passed to your callback.

Comment: `data.data.Items.forEach(function(element) {` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to print the response data before it exists. Your `console.log(resp.response)` line is executing before the DynamoDB query has completed and its results have been unmarshalled. This is a [common gotcha](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) in asynchronous JavaScript.

One way to see the response data in the AWS.Request object is to wait for it, like this (though you would never typically do this in JavaScript):

```
var req = docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
  // as before: handle err, data
)};

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('Response data:', JSON.stringify(req.response.data));
}, 2000);
```

A more common pattern is to use the promise variants of the SDK methods, like this:

```
docClient.query(params).promise()
  .then(data => doSomething(data))
  .catch(err => logError(err));
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. I actually tried and I get results. I admit that I did not know about asynchronous behaviours in JS, my bad. I will have a read to the link you provided my.

On the other hand, if you have any suggestions please do let me know because I am keen to learn how to do proper javascript code (I am a self learner so I would like not to learn "the bad way")

Comment: Async JavaScript is challenging, not least because there are numerous ways to write async code (the mainstream options are callbacks, promises, and async/await). Here are a couple of videos that attempt to describe all three: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoRJizFvM7s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB-OmN1egV8

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look